# How this function/code works in the background

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

me and my clasmates are working on a project on matrix multiplication. I handle the design and he handle the codes. but last week he dropped without explaining the functions of the code.
can someone enlighten me on this?

below is the code and the design.

thanks in advance.

ps. im new in c# so sorry :(

```
private void Compute2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //
        if (Convert.ToInt16(Column1.Text) == Convert.ToInt16(Row2.Text))
        {
            AnswerGrid3.RowCount = Convert.ToInt16(Row1.Text);
            AnswerGrid3.ColumnCount = Convert.ToInt16(Column2.Text);
            AnswerGrid3.AutoResizeColumns();
            AnswerGrid3.AutoResizeRows();
            
            try
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.Matrix1.Rows)
                {
                    int R1 = row.Index;
                    {
                        for (b = 0; b < Matrix2.ColumnCount; b++)
                        {
                            a = 0;
                            for (c = 0; c < Matrix2.RowCount; c++)
                            {
                                decimal D = Convert.ToDecimal(Matrix1.Rows[R1].Cells[c].Value.ToString());
                                decimal E = Convert.ToDecimal(Matrix2.Rows[c].Cells[b].Value.ToString());
                                
                                decimal A = D * E;
                                AnswerGrid3.Rows[R1].Cells[b].Value = decimal.Parse(A.ToString());
                                AnswerGrid3.Rows[R1].Cells[b].Value = a + Convert.ToDouble(AnswerGrid3.Rows[R1].Cells[b].Value);
                                a = Convert.ToDouble(AnswerGrid3.Rows[R1].Cells[b].Value);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //PAG MALI YUNG DATA NA NATYPE LIKE LETTERS SYMBOLS.
                MessageBox.Show("DataType ERROR.");
            }
            
            for (int ansco = 1; ansco <= s; ansco++)

                AnswerGrid3.Columns[ansco - 1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        }
        else
        {
            
            MessageBox.Show("Matrix ERROR. Column of Matrix 1 and Row of Matrix 2 must have same value.");
        }
    }
```

[image: This is the simple design I made.]

Comment: The code you posted is doing matrix subtraction, not matrix multiplication.

Comment: I'm not sure wat which part you'll need help for. Why don't you ask the classmates about it yourself?

Comment: Code is readable do you have an instruction you don't get?

Comment: the only cryptic variable is `ansco` that should stand for "**ans** _wer_  **Co**_lumn_" index.

Comment: @MatthewWatson sorry for my mistakes. i will change it

Comment: @Steven sorry sir, we have no contact since the day he gave this code

Comment: The issue is with no pointer on what you don't understand there is nothing to explain except reading the code out loud. For example `AnswerGrid.ColumnCount = Convert.ToInt16(Column1.Text);`, is "_Set The AnswerGrid column Count to the value of Column1 text converted to int_".

Comment: @DragandDrop yes sir, thats the teacher the way he wants to explain that. sorry

Comment: he wants to elaborate  the code one by one